# adjacent $ operators in R snippets

Tags: r, code-snippets

My desired snippet output would be

`MY_MEDIAN <- my_data$my_col`

where `my_data` and `my_col` are snippet variables to be filled in by the user.

However, writing the snippet requires adjacent dollar signs ($$)--one $ to indicate the dataframe$column relationship and one $ to create the snippet variable. The adjacent dollar signs are bugging up the snippet:

```
snippet demo1
    MY_MEDIAN <- median(${1:my_data}$${2:my_col})
```

produces `MY_MEDIAN <- median(my_data{2:my_variable})`

I have tried using escapes () but this has not solved my problem.

```
snippet demo2
    MY_MEDIAN <- median(${1:my_data}\$${2:my_col})
```

produces `MY_MEDIAN <- median(my_data\{2:my_col})`

```
snippet demo3
    MY_MEDIAN <- median(${1:my_data}\${2:my_col})
```

produces `MY_MEDIAN <- median(my_data${2:my_variable})`

```
MY_MEDIAN <- median(${1:my_data}\\$${2:my_variable})
```

produces `MY_MEDIAN <- median(my_data\{2:my_variable})`

### Closest I can get still has a lingering escape (\) or space (" ")

```
MY_MEDIAN <- median(${1:my_data}\$\\${2:my_variable})
```

produces `MY_MEDIAN <- median(my_data$\my_variable)`

```
MY_MEDIAN <- median(${1:my_data}\$ ${2:my_variable})
```

produces `MY_MEDIAN <- median(my_data$ my_variable)`

Comment: Would the equivalent  `my_data[,my_col]` notation get round the problem?

Comment: @AndrewGustar it probably would, but I wanted to understand why the $$ was causing a problem and how to solve for it.

Comment: The Rstudio snippets help says that a literal `$` can be escaped with a backslash - you will probably need double backslash, the first to escape the second.

Comment: @AndrewGustar I've updated my example to show use of the double escape (\\\) and it current shortcomings. Thank you for suggestion.